# Castle Activerecord. Two collections of the same class

Tags: castle-activerecord

I want to have two collections of same class items in Activerecord.
How to map this?

```
class Project
{
 [HasMany]
 IList<Resource> Resources { get; set; }

 [HasMany]
 IList<Resource> DepartmentResources { get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
 [BelongsTo ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ColumnKey property, e.g.:

```
[HasMany(ColumnKey="res")]
IList<Resource> Resources { get; set; }

[HasMany(ColumnKey="deptres")]
IList<Resource> DepartmentResources { get; set; }

...

public class Resource {
  [BelongsTo("res")]
  Project Project {get;set;}

  [BelongsTo("deptres")]
  Project DeptProject {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I actually ended up deriving two classes from base child object, one for each collection